# How to add up rows and return one of them in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to retrieve rows that have a numeric or null value in the HomeID column and finally return the value with a numeric value if there is a row with the same symbol

```
// my table
+--------+---------+-------+
| Symbol | Home ID | Value |
+--------+---------+-------+
| test   | 1       | value |
| test   | NULL    | value |
| test1  | 2       | value |
| test2  | 3       | vlaue |
+--------+---------+-------+
```

Actually, I did something like that. It added up the symbols for me, but I don't know how to return the poem I need

```
SELECT
    [Symbol],
    COUNT(*) AS CNT
FROM [DB].[dbo].[Table]
GROUP BY
    [Symbol]
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: You have tagged the question MySQL, but the sample code would not run in MySQL.  Confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.homeid is not null or
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2 
                  where t2.symbol = t.symbol and t2.homeid is not null
                 );
```

You can also do this with aggregation, if you just have these three columns and you want exactly one row per symbol:

```
select symbol, max(homeid) as homeid,
       coalesce(max(case when homeid is not null then value end),
                max(value)
               ) as value
from t
group by symbol;
```